# Get SVM classification score in multiclass classification with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I'm working on a project where I'm doing multiclass classification with SVM in OpenCV.

My goal is to get the confidence score of the classification as well as the predicted class.
How can I do that? Right now I'm doing something like

```
float result = mysvm.predict(sample);
```

Having a fairly high amount of classes I prefer to avoid doing a lot of one-vs-all classifications and then calculate the scores.

Since OpenCV SVM is implemented using LibSVM, I'm quite sure that there is a way to do this, but looking at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html doesn't really help.

Thanks for any input provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **opencv/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp**, there is a struct called **CvSVMDecisionFunc**.. It has been used in *line 546* as a *Protected Variable*,

```
CvSVMDecisionFunc* decision_func;
```

What you need to do is to cut that line and paste it as *Public* and then do a complete rebuild of OpenCV.. This variable, **decision_func** contains all the data for specific support vectors (ie, the alpha and rho values)..

Comment: That looks a pretty drastic approach, I'll do it if I can't really find a different way to solve my problem.

I've seen that `bool returnDFVal=false` in the `predict()` funcion does what I need but only for binary classification. No way to get it for multiclass classification?

Comment: Ok, since I lost enough time trying to figure out a better way to do this, I have done as suggested and rebuilt my OpenCV setting the decision function struct to public.
I'm having some difficulties understanding its values though.
I have

 `- rho: -0.9667...`

 `- sv_count: 1`

 `- alpha: {1.00...}`

 `- sv_index: 0`


Not quite what I expected..shouldn't I have a number of support vector that is the number of the classes I am using for classification?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to use `returnDFVal` for multiclass problem. Regarding the `sv_count`, you are right; it should be in accordance with the number of classes (in this case, the labels you provide during the SVM training phase).. In general, I try to use **-1.0** for negative samples and single point positive floats for the rest..

Comment: @powder You can avoid rebuilding OpenCV. Since `decision_func` is protected, you can extend `CvSVM` class and access that variable from the extended class. This way is better.