# SVM for OpenCV C++ Returns Same Confidence Score for Same Class Images

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, rank, surf

I have trained SVM for 20 classes and now for a new image I want to first classify it as one of the 20 trained classes and then display the confidence score on the basis of which it was classified.

**Problem:** When I tested some of the images of class 1, they all returned the same confidence score. I know each image should have a different score on the basis of which it was classified. So I know there is a problem in my code.

I have even changed the instance variable float *decision_function on the "opencv" framework from protected to public and rebuilt it, but the problem is still not solved.

I want to compute the correct scores, as I want to later rank the images that best match my query image on the basis of the confidence scores.

Please let me know why I am getting the same confidence score for each image in the same class and where in my code have I made the mistake.

```
Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create("FlannBased"); 
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = new SurfDescriptorExtractor();
SurfFeatureDetector detector(500);// hemessian threshold

int dictionarySize = 100;  //number of clusters=100
TermCriteria tc(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 0.001);
int retries = 1;
int flags = KMEANS_PP_CENTERS;
BOWKMeansTrainer bowTrainer(dictionarySize, tc, retries, flags);
BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowDE(extractor, matcher);

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int i,j;
    Mat dictionary; // creating a dictionary
    FileStorage fs("dictionary_new.yml", FileStorage::READ);
    fs ["vocabulary"]>> dictionary;
    fs.release();

    bowDE.setVocabulary(dictionary);
    Mat labels(0, 1, CV_32FC1);  //to store labels of images
    Mat trainingData(0, dictionarySize, CV_32FC1);
    int k=0;

    CvSVMParams params;
    params.kernel_type=CvSVM::RBF;
    params.svm_type=CvSVM::C_SVC;
    params.gamma=0.50625000000000009;
    params.C=312.50000000000000;
    params.term_crit=cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,100,0.000001);
    CvSVM svm;

    svm.load("svm_new.yml");
    cout<<"Processing evaluation data..."<<endl;
    string tags[] = {"none","Plane","Bike","Face","Car","Bag","binocular","Gloves","Bread_Maker","Revolver","Ring","Guitar","Elephant","boat","French_horn","Gorilla","Headphone","Flower","Penguin","Tiger","Laptop"};
    Mat evalData(0, dictionarySize, CV_32FC1);
    k=0;
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoint2;
    Mat bowDescriptor2;
    Mat img2; //to load an image

    img2 = imread("3 (14).jpg");
    detector.detect(img2, keypoint2);
    bowDE.compute(img2, keypoint2, bowDescriptor2);
    evalData.push_back(bowDescriptor2);
    float response = svm.predict(bowDescriptor2, true);
    float confidence=0;
    int f_to_i=(int)response;
    confidence=1.0/(1.0+exp(-response));
    cout<<"\n\nIt's a "<<tags[f_to_i]<<" and its confidence: "<<confidence;

    _getch();
    return 0; 
}
```

**Computed Scores:**

```
1 (1).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (2).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (3).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (4).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (5).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (6).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (7).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (8).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (9).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (10).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (11).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (12).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (13).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (14).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (15).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (16).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (17).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (18).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (19).jpg,Plane,0.731059
1 (20).jpg,Plane,0.731059
```

Comment: Changing a variable from protected to public should NEVER affect a program's output.

Comment: I followed this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810228/get-svm-classification-score-in-multiclass-classification-with-opencv?rq=1) because I am somewhat having the same problem. @MSalters

Comment: try another kernel, different svm params but note, that when you load an svm from file, your svm params will get overwritten too (from data inside the xml)

Comment: @berak Like you said, I made sure that my kernel and params are the same in the code as well as in the data of the yml I am loading. But I am still getting the same score for a whole class.

Comment: did you really want a regression, not a classification ? else set the flag in `pedict` to false.

Comment: @berak I want to use the computed scores to rank my images that's why I set the flag in predict to true, but all I am getting are the same scores for 1 class of images. Because of this I am unable to sort images on the basis of the scores.

Comment: @berak The images are classified correctly as Planes but the computed scores are the same as you can see in the output I have shared.

Comment: ah, ok. thanks for clarification. unfortunately, no idea, atm.

Comment: @barek Okay, no problem. Right now I am ranking my images differently so it's not big of an issue but using right scores computed through svm would definitely improve my ranking. So I am hoping someone would help me get the right scores. :)

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem. The problem is that you can't get the response with svm.predict(bowDescriptor2, true) when you have more then 2 classes. If the problem is multiclass OpenCv SVM will return just the class label number. And that's explains why you're having the same values.

Look at the documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-predict

"returnDFVal – Specifies a type of the return value. If true and the problem is 2-class classification then the method returns the decision function value that is signed distance to the margin, else the function returns a class label (classification) or estimated function value (regression)."

A possible solution is to modify the 
float CvSVM::predict(const float* row_sample, int row_len, bool returnDFVal) method. There you can do changes to get the decisionFunctionValues for each class.

Look at a part of the code:
...

```
for (i = 0; i < class_count; i++)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j < class_count; j++, df++)
    {
        sum = -df->rho;
        int sv_count = df->sv_count;
        for (k = 0; k < sv_count; k++)
            sum += df->alpha[k] * buffer[df->sv_index[k]];

        vote[sum > 0 ? i : j]++;
    }
}

for (i = 1, k = 0; i < class_count; i++)
{
    if (vote[i] > vote[k])
        k = i;
}
result = returnDFVal && class_count == 2 ? (float)sum : (float)(class_labels->data.i[k]);
```