# Confidence score or probability in SVM

Tags: matlab, opencv, svm, emgucv, libsvm

I'm using a multi-class SVM classifier in EmguCV. I need confidence score of SVM for each of the classes. for example I don't need that SVM just declares class number, I need it tells me P(classnumbers| input) for different Classes.
How can I obtain this probability or score in EmguCV?(multi-class)

if there is no way, Is any solution for multi-class SVM classifier in matlab?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `EmguCV`, but in `OpenCV` you can do something like this to obtain probability in `SVM`:

```
CvSVM svm;   // declare your classifier;
// then do your training process here
svm.train(featuresToBeTrained, labelsToBeTrained, cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), params); // params are the svm parameters, you can use libsvm to optimize them.
//libsvm website: https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/

// perform prediction
double confidenceScore = svm.predict(featuresToBePredected, true); // this will give you a signed distance to the margin.

// Then you can normalize the score to improve it, one best way is to use sigmoid function.
double finalScore = sigmoidFunc(confidenceScore, sigmoidA, sigmoidB); // sigmoidA and sigmoidB are params for sigmoid function, take wikipedia for reference

// You can define sigmoid function like this    
double sigmoidFunc(double confidenceScore, double A, double B)
{
    double fApB = confidenceScore*A + B;
    // 1-p used later; avoid catastrophic cancellation
    if (fApB >= 0)
    {
        return 1.0 - (exp(-fApB) / (1.0 + exp(-fApB)));
    }
    else
    {
        return 1.0 - (1.0 / (1.0 + exp(fApB)));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

**Update**

For a multiclass case, take a reference to the following link:
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810228/get-svm-classification-score-in-multiclass-classification-with-opencv)

Comment: Tnx alot Derman :). I think it works only for two-class Classifiers am I right? In EmguCV, there is no DecisionFunction that I can turn its flag to true unfortunately

Comment: I mean I don't access to confidence score of SVM

Comment: I don't think multiclass situation is very different from a two-class one, since you let SVM know how many classes are there in your dataset during training.

Comment: yeah you're right but when I choose SVMType parameter, instead of One-Class option I select C-SVC(multi-class) and for this type of SVM the "ture"  label in Predict(featuresToBePredected, true) does not work.

Comment: This is not a correct method, it has no probabilistic meaning, you should use **Platt's scaling** instead.