# Reject unknown gestures using multiclass svm

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I am currently implementing a hand recognition system to recognize hand gestures in real time. I have used Histogram of Oriented Gradients as feature extraction and Multiclass SVM as classifier. For e.g I have trained

1. Gesture A as label 1
2. Gesture B as label 2
3. Gesture C as label 3
4. Gesture D as label 4

Now when i am providing gesture for matching it is recognising Gesture E as Gesture D. Gesture F as Gesture A. I want to know how to reject unknown gestures which do not form part of my training data. To train the training data,I used svm->train function and to do matching I have used svm->predict.

Comment: Multiclass SVM does not have a "rejection" mechanism the way you want it to be. A viable approach could be to train a negative class #5 with all the samples that you know to be not A, B, C or D.

Comment: Is it possible to use euclidean distance to calculate the distance between the predicted vector and tested vector? And use that as a clue to know if they belong to the same class.

Comment: You could try. A better heuristic would be SVM output scores. But both are brittle heuristics.

Comment: How to get SVM output score?

Comment: OpenCV does not expose the scores directly but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810228/get-svm-classification-score-in-multiclass-classification-with-opencv shows a workaround. My recommendation is not to rely on the confidence scores or any distance value on the input space though.

Comment: So is there any other way? Or any other classifier better than SVM which deals with my problems in a better way?